# Segmentation fault while creating Huffman Tree in C

Tags: c

I am currently trying to create a [Huffman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding) tree from a sorted priority list.

The sorted list and the Huffman tree are of the same struct:

```
typedef struct _TreeNode{
    unsigned char ch;
    int freq;
    struct _TreeNode* left;
    struct _TreeNode* right;
    struct _TreeNode* next;
} TreeNode;
```

When trying to create the tree from the priority list, I use the following code:

```
TreeNode* create_tree(TreeNode* priority_list){
    while(priority_list -> next != NULL){
        TreeNode* root = malloc(sizeof(*root));
        root -> left = pop_tree(&priority_list);
        root -> right = pop_tree(&priority_list);
        root -> freq = (root -> left -> freq) + (root -> right -> freq);
        priority_list = enqueue_tree(priority_list, root);
    }
    return priority_list;
}

TreeNode* pop_tree(TreeNode** pq){
    TreeNode* popped = *pq;
    *pq = (*pq) -> next;
    popped -> next = NULL;
    return popped;
}

TreeNode* enqueue_tree(TreeNode* pq, TreeNode* new_node){
    if(new_node -> freq < pq -> freq){
        new_node -> next = pq;
        return new_node;
    }
    TreeNode* curr = pq;
    TreeNode* temp = pq;
    while(curr -> next != NULL && (curr -> freq <= new_node -> freq)){
        temp = curr;
        curr = curr -> next;
    }
    new_node -> next = curr;
    temp -> next = new_node;
    return pq;
}
```

The `enqueue_tree` function is similar to the function used to create the initially sorted `priority_list`, which the output is correct. However, when I run this code it seems to get caught in an endless loop. The `pop_tree` is a modified function from a previous code that was for a simple linked list, and worked as expected, but could potentially be the problem. So, my question is, what could be causing the segmentation fault / endless loop?

Comment: i'm confused. is it a seg fault or an infinite loop?

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus when running my code I get "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: it's worth looking at the core to see which line it crashes on. the only definite bug i see is when malloc fails

Comment: Looks odd to `root -> left = pop_tree(&priority_list);` and the same with `root -> right`

Comment: the line "TreeNode* root = malloc(sizeof(*root));" seems wrong. It will only reserve space for the pointer. Have you tried with sizeof(TreeNode) instead ?